# How to make a request to coinbase exchange API from localhost?

Tags: javascript, http, cryptography, fetch-api, coinbase-api

When I run the following code from the client side in JavaScript as the coinbase cloud documentation says https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference/exchangerestapi_getcoinbaseaccounts

```
  const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'cb-access-key': 'Apikey',
    'cb-access-passphrase': 'Mypassphrase',
    'cb-access-sign': cb_access_sign,
    'cb-access-timestamp': cb_access_timestamp
  }
};

fetch('https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/coinbase-accounts', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

When I do it with axios the same thing happens.

The following error appears in console:

> "Access to fetch at 'https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/coinbase-accounts' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Request header field cb-access-passphrase is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in the browser, you need to do it from the web server. You can either display the data when the page loads or use vue/react and write your own interaction with the webserver.

edit: doing this in the browser makes your keys visible...

Answer (score 0):

Coinbase API has misconfigured CORS (or intentionally require you to make API calls from a server). Regardless, this makes it very hard to test in a dev environment. This can be solved using a proxy. This can be configured using [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) which changes the api call flow from:

```
Client (localhost:3000) <-> Coinbase API (api.exchange.coinbase.com)
```

to

```
Client (localhost:3000) <-> Proxy Server (www.your-proxy-server.com) <-> Coinbase API (api.exchange.coinbase.com)
```

In summary, coinbase will only see a request coming from your proxy server and does not care/know where the proxy server sends back the data. Cors-anywhere will also include the headers and data along with the request.

Do not use public cor-anywhere servers unless you are quickly testing something. It is best to set up your own.

**Using Firebase**

I used [cors-server](https://github.com/Isoaxe/cors-server) to set mine up using firebase functions. You want your Firebase functions to look like the following:

```
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const corsAnywhere = require('cors-anywhere');
const cors = require("cors")({origin:true})

const corsServer = corsAnywhere.createServer({
    originWhitelist: [
      'http://localhost:3000',
    ],
    requireHeader: ['origin', 'x-requested-with'],
    removeHeaders: ['cookie', 'cookie2'],
});

exports.proxy = onRequest((request, response) => {
  cors(request,response,() =>{
    corsServer.emit('request', request, response);
  })    
});
```

and an example of a request in your client code

```
return(
       axios({
                url: `https://proxy-your-function-id.a.run.app/https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/profiles`,
                headers: await getHeaders(options),
                method: 'GET',
                data: options.body
             }).then((response)=>{
                return(response)
             }).catch((err)=>{
                return(err.response)
      })
)
```

Edit: It should also be noted that Coinbase is getting rid of Coinbase Pro and its API end of 2022. Coinbase exchange and its API will still be available at https://api.exchange.coinbase.com however Pro users will be merged into Advanced Trading on their main platform which uses oAuth to link the API (or standard keys for personal projects).